# How to redirect only existing pages of a website to the new domain but exclude some specific folders?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I wish to setup redirects in the .htaccess file of the old domain so that only working pages get redirected to the new domain. Any links to the non-existing pages of the old domain should display 404 error. So, for example

OLD Domain: https://www.oldurl.com
NEW Domain: https://www.newurl.com

I want the following redirects to work

```
https://www.oldurl.com => https://www.newurl.com
https://www.oldurl.com/some-page.php => https://www.newurl.com/some-page.php
https://www.oldurl.com/folder/some-page.php => https://www.newurl.com/folder/some-page.php
```

But I do not want the following redirects to point to the new site. They should display 404 error.

```
https://www.oldurl.com/bad-folder
https://www.oldurl.com/bad-link.php
https://www.oldurl.com/non-existing-page.html
```

etc.

So, in short, any valid page that already exists on the old website should be redirected to new website except for some specific folders and non-existing links (they should point to 404 error page on old website)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your old server supposed to determine which are “non-existing links”? The only way to do that, would be if you did not have any routing system set up on top of the web server to begin with, so that all URLs match directly onto folders or files, and all those folders and files still existed – is that the case?

Comment: No, for this we can manually create individual redirects for all the valid links (files and folders) in the htaccess file of old domain. So, all other links would be non-existing pages/folders and they should be directed to the 404 page on old domain.

Comment: So where is the problem then? Any request for a URL that you did not redirect elsewhere, and that the server can not map to an existing folder or file either, should _automatically_ result in a 404.